# installation GLCD ks0108 with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

can someone help with this problem? I'm a newbie for this project, and i have searched for all the time and i can't find the tutorial's.
Can someone help me to teach me how to wiring GLCD with module KS0108 with raspberry pi and python code?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/Mezgrman/pyLCD

- There are instructions to install the modules, change the wiring, and example code to get started with.

Comment: can you posting the wiring diagram please? because i'm newbie on raspi and i cant understand by read github, thanks

Comment: Really?  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/   or   https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio-plus-and-raspi2/README.md for B+

Comment: i don't understand when it said we need to use wiringPi's wpi_mode_GPIO, can you explain it? and its using bcm mode or board mode for the GPIO? and someone have done with it?